# I cannot boot into Ubuntu 12.10 after upgrade from 12.04.

Tags: boot, dual-boot, dist-upgrade

I'm using Ubuntu alongside Windows 7. 
The upgrade went fine but after reboot I'm getting grub prompt that says `grub>`
How can I get Ubuntu back without losing Windows 7?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this post](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair#A2nd_option_%3a_install_Boot-Repair_in_Ubuntu) , I had the same issue I fixed with using it.